# Putting an external enum in a .h into a class

Tags: c++

My current class creation is set up as so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

//Class Student
class Student {
    private:
        string student_ID;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string email;
        int age;
        int daysToComplete[3];
        enum DegreeProgram;
```

`enum DegreeProgram;` is my issue and question.

In an external .h file I have

```
enum DegreeProgram {SECURITY, NETWORK, SOFTWARE};
```

I am wanting to put that enumerated data type into the class where I can then make a setter and getter to modify the DegreeProgram between those values.

How can I bring in that enumerated data type I created in the external .h into my class creation?

My current getter and setter looks as such.

```
string getDegreeProgram() {
  return DegreeProgram;
};
void setDegreeProgram(int program) {
  DegreeProgram = program;
  return 0;
};
```

I'm quite new to C++ and more familiar with JS and Python.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think all you need to do is give the member an identifier: `enum DegreeProgram myEnumMember;` and work with the member variable. Right now what you have is almost the same as `int;`

Comment: Side note: Logic is logic, but pretty much everything else you learned from Python and Javascript needs to be relearned. C++ is a very, very different beast. If you try to write C++ the way you write Python, your code will be sub-optimal at best and more likely [a complete mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)

Comment: Understood.  I taught myself JS, React, and Python.  Now I'm working on finishing my degree and it's taking me through C++ classes.  No complaints. Just as you said, a very very different beast.

Comment: are you sure you don't just need to `#include "header_file_containing_enum_degree_program_declaration.h"` ? :)